# A proof of Kantorovich duality

Tags: optimal-transport

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces. Let $P(X), P(Y)$ be the spaces of all Borel probability measures on $X,Y$ respectively. Let $c: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \cup\{+\infty\}$ be lower semi-continuous. Fix $\mu \in P(X)$ and $\nu \in P(Y)$.

- $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is the set of $\pi \in P(X \times Y)$ such that for all measurable subsets $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$,
  $$
  \pi[A \times Y]=\mu[A], \quad \pi[X \times B]=\nu[B].
  $$
- $\Phi_{c}$ is the set of all $(\varphi, \psi) \in L^{1}(d \mu) \times L^{1}(d \nu)$ satisfying
  $$
  \varphi(x)+\psi(y) \leq c(x, y)
  $$
  for $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$ and $\nu$-almost all $y \in Y$.
- For $\pi \in P(X \times Y)$ and $(\varphi, \psi) \in L^{1}(d \mu) \times L^{1}(d \nu)$, let $$I[\pi]:=\int_{X \times Y} c d \pi, \quad J(\varphi, \psi):=\int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu .$$

Then
$$
\inf _{\Pi(\mu, \nu)} I[\pi]=\sup _{\Phi_{c}} J(\varphi, \psi) .
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that
$$
\sup _{\Phi_{c} \cap C_{b}} J(\varphi, \psi) \leq \sup _{\Phi_{c} \cap L^{1}} J(\varphi, \psi) \leq \inf _{\Pi(\mu, \nu)} I[\pi].
$$

So it remains to prove
$$
\inf _{\Pi(\mu, \nu)} I[\pi] \le \sup _{\Phi_{c} \cap C_{b}} J(\varphi, \psi) .
$$

To simplify notations, let $\varphi \oplus \psi: (x,y) \mapsto \varphi(x)+\psi(y)$. We have
$$
\inf _{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} I[\pi]=\inf _{\pi \in M_{+}(X \times Y)}\left(I[\pi]+\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 \text { if } \pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu) \\
+\infty \text { else }
\end{array}\right)\right.
$$
with $M_+(X \times Y)$ the space of non-negative Borel measures on $X\times Y$. Also,
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 \text { if } \pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu) \\
+\infty \text { else }
\end{array}\right\}=\sup \left \{ \int \varphi d \mu+\int \psi d \nu-\int \varphi \oplus \psi d \pi \,\middle\vert\, (\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y) \right \},
$$

It follows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
 &\inf _{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} I[\pi]\\
 =&\inf _{\pi \in M_{+}(X \times Y)} \sup  \left \{ \int_{X \times Y} c d \pi +\int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu - \int_{X \times Y} \varphi \oplus \psi d \pi \,\middle\vert\, (\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y) \right\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

> 1. Let us first assume that $X, Y$ are **compact**.

- Let $E:=C_{b}(X \times Y)$ be the set of all bounded continuous functions on $X \times Y$, equipped with its usual supremum norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.
- Because $X,Y$ are **compact**, so is $X\times Y$. So $E$ coincides with the space $C_{0}(X \times Y)$ of all continuous functions vanishing at infinity on $X \times Y$.
- By Riesz' theorem, the topological dual $E^*$ of $E$ can be identified with the space of regular Radon measures, $M(X \times Y)$, normed by total variation.
- Moreover, a **nonnegative** linear form on $E$ corresponds with a regular **nonnegative** Borel measure.

Then we introduce
$$
\begin{gathered}
\Theta: u \in E \longmapsto\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0 &\text {if } u \geq-c, \\
+\infty &\text {else}.
\end{array}\right.\\
\text{}\\
\Xi: u \in E \longmapsto\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu &\begin{align*}
&\text {if } u = \varphi \oplus \psi \text{ for}\\
&  \text{some } (\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y)
\end{align*},\\
+\infty &\text {else. }
\end{array}\right.
\end{gathered}
$$

It's easy to verify that $\Theta, \Xi$ satisfy the condition of [Fenchel-Rockafellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%27s_duality_theorem#Mathematical_theorem) duality, so
$$
\inf _{u\in E}[\Theta(u)+\Xi(u)] = \max _{\pi \in E^{*}}\left[-\Theta^{*}\left(-\pi\right)-\Xi^{*}\left(\pi\right)\right].
$$

It's clear that
$$
\begin{align*}
\inf _{u\in E}[\Theta(u)+\Xi(u)] &= \inf \left\{\int_{X} \varphi d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi d \nu \,\middle\vert\, (\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y) \text{ s.t. } \varphi \oplus \psi \geq -c \right\} \\
&=-\sup \left\{J(\varphi, \psi) \mid (\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_{c}\cap C_{b}\right\}.
\end{align*}
$$

Next, we compute the Legendre-Fenchel transforms of $\Theta, \Xi$. First, for any $\pi \in E^*$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Theta^{*}(-\pi) =\sup _{u \in E}\left\{-\int u d \pi \,\middle\vert\, u \geq-c\right\}
= \sup _{u \in E}\left\{\int u d \pi \,\middle\vert\, u \leq c\right\} .
\end{aligned}
$$

- If $\pi$ is not **nonnegative**, then there exists a **positive** function $v \in E$ such that $\int v d \pi<0$. Then, the choice $u=\lambda v$, with $\lambda \rightarrow-\infty$, shows that the supremum is $+\infty$.
- On the other hand, if $\pi$ is **nonnegative**, then the supremum is clearly $\int c d \pi$. This is because lower semi-continuous and bounded from below function is a limit of an increasing sequence of Lipschitz continuous functions.

Thus
$$
\Theta^{*}(-\pi) = \begin{cases}
\int c d \pi &\text {if } \pi \in M_{+}(X \times Y) \\
+\infty &\text {else}.
\end{cases}
$$

We also have
$$
\begin{align*}
\Xi^{*}(\pi) &= \sup_{u\in E} \left \{ \int ud\pi - \int \varphi d \mu- \int \psi d\nu  \,\middle\vert\,  u = \varphi \oplus \psi \text{ for some } (\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y) \right \} \\
&= \begin{cases}
0  &\text {if } \quad  \forall(\varphi, \psi) \in C_b(X) \times C_b(Y) : \int \varphi \oplus \psi d \pi= \int \varphi d \mu+\int \psi d \nu \\
 +\infty & \text {else}
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
0  &\text {if } \quad  \pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu) \\
 +\infty & \text {else}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$

It follows that
$$
\max _{\pi \in E^{*}}\left[-\Theta^{*}\left(-\pi\right)-\Xi^{*}\left(\pi\right)\right] = \max _{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu) \cap M_{+}(X \times Y)} -\int c d \pi = - \min _{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c d \pi.
$$
Hence
$$
-\sup \left\{J(\varphi, \psi) \mid (\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_{c} \cap C_{b}\right\} = - \min _{\pi \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int c d \pi.
$$

> 2. $c$ is bounded.

Fix
$$
\pi_* \in \operatorname{argmin}_{\pi  \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)}I [\pi].
$$

Then $\pi_*$ is tight, so there are compact sets $X_n \subset X$ and $Y_n \subset Y$ such that $\mu(X_n^c), \nu(Y_n^c) \le \delta$. Let $Z_n  := X_n \times Y_n$. Then $\pi (Z_n^c) \le 2\delta$. We define $\pi_n \in \mathcal P(Z_n)$ by
$$
\pi_n := \frac{1_{Z_n}\pi_*}{\pi_* (Z_n)}.
$$

Let $\mu_n := P_\sharp^{X_n} \pi_{n} \in \mathcal P(X_n)$ and $\nu_n := P_\sharp^{Y_n} \pi_{n} \in  \mathcal P(Y_n)$ be marginals of $\pi_n$. Let
$$
I_n[\pi] := \int_{Z_n} c d \pi \quad \forall \pi \in \Pi(\mu_n, \nu_n).
$$

Fix
$$
\tilde \pi_{n} \in \operatorname{argmin}_{\pi  \in \Pi(\mu_n, \nu_n)} I_n [\pi].
$$

Define $\pi_{*n}$ by
$$
\pi_{*n} := \pi_* (Z_n) \tilde \pi_{n} + 1_{Z_n^c} \pi_*.
$$

It is easy to verify that $\pi_{*n} \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
I[\pi_*] &\le I[\pi_{*n}] \\
&= \int_{X\times Y} c d \pi_{*n} \\
 &= \pi_*(Z_n)\int_{Z_n} c d \tilde \pi_n + \int_{Z_n^c} c d \pi_* \\
 &\le \pi_*(Z_n) I_n [\tilde \pi_n] + 2 \delta \|c\|_\infty \\
 & \le I_n [\tilde \pi_n] + 2\delta \|c\|_\infty.
\end{align}
$$

Now we introduce
$$
J_n:  L^{1}(\mu_{n}) \times L^{1}(\nu_{n}) \to \mathbb R, (\varphi, \psi) \mapsto \int_{X_{n}} \varphi d \mu_{n}+\int_{Y_{n}} \psi d \nu_{n}.
$$

Let $\Phi_{c,n}$ be the set of all $(\varphi, \psi) \in L^{1}(\mu_n) \times L^{1}(\nu_n)$ satisfying $\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \leq c(x, y)$ for $\mu_n$-almost all $x \in X_n$ and $\nu_n$-almost all $y \in Y_n$. By step 1, we know that
$$
\inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu_n, \nu_n)} I_n [\pi] = \sup_{(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_{c,n}} J_n (\varphi, \psi).
$$

In particular, there is $(\varphi_n, \psi_n) \in \Phi_{c,n}$ such that
$$
J_n (\varphi_n, \psi_n) \ge \sup_{(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_{c,n}} J_n (\varphi, \psi) - \delta.
$$

To ensure $\varphi_n (x)+\psi_n (y) \leq c(x, y)$ for all $x \in X_n$ and all $y \in Y_n$. We redefine $\varphi_n, \psi_n$ such that $\varphi_n, \psi_n$ take value $-\infty$ on their null sets respectively. WLOG, we assume $\delta <1$. Then $J_n (\varphi_n, \psi_n) \ge -1$. Then there is $(x_n, y_n) \in Z_n$ such that
$$
\varphi_n(x_n)+\psi_n(y_n) \ge -1.
$$

If we replace $(\varphi_n, \psi_n)$ by $(\varphi_n +s, \psi_n-s)$ for some real number $s$, we do not change the value of $J_n (\varphi_n, \psi_n)$, so the resulting couple is still admissible. By a proper choice of $s$, we can ensure
$$
\varphi_n (x_n) \ge -\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad\psi_n (y_n) \ge -\frac{1}{2}.
$$

This implies for all $(x,y) \in Z_n$,
$$
\varphi_n(x) \le c(x, y_n) - \psi_n(y_n) \le c(x, y_n) + 1/2,\\
\psi_n(y) \le c(x_n, y) - \varphi_n(x_n) \le c(x_n, y) + 1/2.
$$

Define $\psi_n^c$ by
$$
\psi_n^c (x) := \inf_{y\in Y_n} [c(x, y) - \psi_n(y)] \quad \forall x \in X_n.
$$

Moreover,
$$
\inf_{y\in Y_n} [c(x,y)-c(x_n, y)] - 1/2 \le \psi_n^c (x) \le c (x, y_n)  - \psi_n (y_n) \le c(x, y_n) + 1/2.
$$

It follows from $c$ is bounded that $\psi_n^c$ is bounded. Hence $\psi_n^c \in L^1(\mu)$. It follows from $\varphi_n(x)+\psi_n(y) \leq c(x, y)$ that $\varphi_n \le \psi_n^c$ on $X_n$. This implies $J_n (\psi_n^c , \psi_n) \ge J_n (\varphi_n, \psi_n)$. Similarly, we define $\psi_n^{cc}$ by
$$
\psi_n^{cc}  (y) := \inf_{x\in X_n} [c(x, y) - \psi_n^c (x)] \quad \forall y \in Y_n.
$$

For all $y\in Y_n$, we have
$$
\inf_{x\in X_n} [c(x,y)-c(x, y_n)] - 1/2 \le \psi_n^{cc} (y) \le c(x_n, y) - \psi_n^c (x_n) \le c(x_n, y) - \varphi_n (x_n) \le c(x_n,y)+1/2.
$$

So $\psi_n^{cc}$ is also bounded and thus $\psi_n^{cc} \in L^1(\nu)$. Moreover,
$$
\psi_n^c (x) + \psi_n^{cc} (y) = \psi_n^c (x) + \inf_{z \in X} [c(z, y) - \psi_n^c(z)] \le \psi_n^c(x) + [c(x, y) - \psi_n^c(x)] = c(x,y).
$$

Then $(\psi_n^c, \psi_n^{cc}) \in \Phi_c$. Also
$$
\psi_n^{cc} (y) = \inf_{x\in X_n} [c(x, y) - \psi_n^c(x)] \ge \inf_{x\in X_n} [c(x, y) - [c(c,y) - \psi_n (y)]] = \psi_n (y) \quad \forall y \in Y_n.
$$

This implies
$$
J_n (\psi_n^c , \psi_n^{cc}) \ge J_n(\psi_n^c, \psi_n) \ge J_n (\varphi_n, \psi_n).
$$

In particular,
$$
\psi_n^c (x) \ge - \|c\|_\infty -1/2 \quad \text{and} \quad \psi_n^{cc} (y) \ge - \|c\|_\infty -1/2.
$$

Indeed,
$$
\begin{align*}
J(\psi_n^c, \psi_n^{cc})
&= \int_{X} \psi_n^c d \mu+\int_{Y} \psi_n^{cc} d \nu  \\
&= \int_{X \times Y}[\psi_n^c (x) + \psi_n^{cc} (y)] d \pi_{*n}(x, y) \\
&= \pi_{*}[Z_n] \int_{Z_n}[ \psi_n^c (x) + \psi_n^{cc} (y)] d \tilde \pi_{n}(x, y) +\int_{Z_n^{c}}[\psi_n^c(x)+\psi_n^{cc}(y)] d \pi_{*}(x, y) \\
&\ge (1-2 \delta) \left (\int_{X_n} \psi_n^c d \mu_n+\int_{Y_n}   \psi_n^{cc} d \nu_n \right )-(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \pi_{*}[Z_n^c] \\
&\geq(1-2 \delta) J_n( \psi_n^c , \psi_n^{cc} )-2(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \delta \\
&\geq(1-2 \delta) J_n({\varphi}_n, {\psi}_n)-2(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \delta \\
&\geq(1-2 \delta) \left ( \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu_n, \nu_n)} I_n [\pi] - \delta \right)-2(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \delta \\
&= (1-2 \delta)( I_n [\tilde \pi_n] -\delta)-2(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \delta \\
&\ge (1-2 \delta)(I[\pi_{*}] -(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \delta)-2(2\|c\|_{\infty}+1) \delta.
\end{align*}
$$

The result then follows by taking the limit $\delta \to 0^+$.

> 3. Let us assume that $X, Y$ are **not** compact, and that $c$ is lower semi-continuous on $X \times Y$.