# Construct the $c$-transform $(\overline \varphi, \overline \psi)$ of $(\varphi, \psi)$

Tags: optimal-transport

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record. See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

Anyway, it is written as problem. Have fun! :)

---

Let $X,Y$ be Polish spaces and $c:X \times Y \to \mathbb [0, +\infty)$ lower semi-continuous. We fix Borel probability measures (b.p.m.) $\mu \in \mathcal P(X)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$.

- Let $\Phi_c$ the collection of $(\varphi: X \to \mathbb R, \psi: Y \to \mathbb R) \in L_1(\mu) \times L_1(\nu)$ such that $\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \le c(x,y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.
- Let
  $$
  J (\varphi, \psi) := \int_X \varphi d \mu + \int \psi d \nu \quad \forall (\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c.
  $$
- Now assume a reglarity condition that there are $c_X: X \to \mathbb R$ and $c_Y: Y \to \mathbb R$ such that $c_X \in L_1(\mu), c_Y \in L_1 (\nu)$, and $c (x, y) \le c_X(x)+c_Y(y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

> Then for each $(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c$, there is an improved pair $(\varphi', \psi') \in \Phi_c$ such that
>
> - $J (\varphi, \psi) = J (\varphi', \psi')$.
> - $\varphi' (x) \le c_X (x)$ and $\psi' (y) \le c_Y (y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

Such pair is constructed by the method of $c$-transform and is used to construct an optimal solution of the dual problem in [Kantorovich duality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4449059/a-proof-of-kantorovich-duality/4449061).

Comment: You are expected to follow guidelines in [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C129.4767) regardless of whether or not you plan to answer the question.  You asked a problem statement question as though transcribed from an exercise.  You need context, as discussed in the link.  The disclaimer does not give you license to not those guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c$.

- There are a $\mu$-null set $N_x$ and $\nu$-null net $N_y$ such that $\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \le c(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in N_x^c \times N_y^c$.
- We re-define $\varphi, \psi$ by letting them take value $-\infty$ on $N_x, N_y$ respectively. In this way, $\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \le c(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.

We define $\varphi^c$ by
$$
\varphi^c (y) := \inf_{x\in X} [c(x,y) - \varphi(x)].
$$

- The infimum of a collection of extended real-valued measurable functions is again a measurable function, so $\varphi^c$ is measurable.
- There is $x_0 \in N^c_x$, so $\varphi^c (y) \le c(x_0,y)-\varphi(x_0) <+\infty$ for all $y \in Y$.
- Given $y\in Y$, $\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \le c(x,y)$ for all $x \in X$, so $\varphi^c (y) \ge \psi(y)$ for all $y\in Y$.

We define $\varphi^{cc}$ by
$$
\varphi^{cc} (x) := \inf_{y\in Y} [c(x,y) - \varphi^c (y)].
$$

For all $x\in X$,
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi^{cc} (x) &= \inf_{y\in Y} \left [c(x,y) - \inf_{z\in X} [c(z,y) - \varphi(z)] \right] \\
&= \inf_{y\in Y} \left [c(x,y) + \sup_{z\in X} [-c(z,y) + \varphi(z)] \right] \\
&= \inf_{y\in Y} \sup_{z\in X} [c(x,y) -c(z,y) + \varphi(z)]  \\
&\ge \inf_{y\in Y}  \varphi(x) =\varphi(x) \quad \text{by picking} \quad z=x.
\end{align}
$$

There is $y_0 \in N_y^c$. Then
$$
\varphi^{cc} (x) \le c(x, y_0) - \varphi^c (y_0) \le c(x, y_0) - \psi(y_0) <+\infty \quad \forall x\in X.
$$
For all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$,
$$
\varphi^{cc} (x) + \varphi^c (y) = \inf_{z\in Y} [c(x,z) - \varphi^c(z)] + \varphi^c (y) \le [c(x,y) - \varphi^c (y)] + \varphi^c (y)= c(x,y).
$$

---

- There are a $\mu$-null set $M_x$ and $\nu$-null set $M_y$ such that $c (x, y) \le c_X(x)+c_Y(y)$ for all $(x, y) \in M_x^c \times M_y^c$.
- We re-define $c_X, c_Y$ such that $c_X (x) = c_Y(y) := +\infty$ for all $(x, y) \in M_x \times M_y$. In this way, $c(x,y) \le c_X(x)+c_Y(y)$ for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.

Let
$$
a := \inf_{y\in Y} [c_Y(y) - \varphi^c (y)].
$$

First,
$$
a \le c_Y(y_0) - \varphi^c (y_0) \le c_Y(y_0) - \psi (y_0) < +\infty.
$$

There is $x_1 \in (N_x \cup M_x)^c$, so
$$
\begin{align}
c_Y(y) - \varphi^c (y) &= c_Y(y) - \inf_{x\in X} [c(x,y) - \varphi(x)] \\
&= \sup_{x\in X} [c_Y(y)-c(x,y) + \varphi(x)] \\
&\ge \sup_{x\in X} [\varphi(x)-c_X(x)] \\
&\ge \varphi(x_1)-c_X(x_1) \\
&> -\infty.
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $a \in \mathbb R$. Clearly, $a \le c_Y(y) - \varphi^c (y)$ for all $y\in Y$, so $\varphi^c+a \le c_Y$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
(\varphi^{cc} (x)-a) - c_X(x) &= \inf_{y\in Y} [c(x,y) - \varphi^c (y)]-a - c_X(x) \\
&= \inf_{y\in Y} [(c(x,y)-c_X(x)) - \varphi^c (y)] -a \\
&\le \inf_{y\in Y} [c_Y(y) - \varphi^c (y)] -a \\&=0.
\end{align}
$$

Clearly, $(\varphi', \psi') := (\varphi^{cc}-a, \varphi^c+a)$ satisfies the requirement.