# Is this shorter attempt on the existence of the maximizer in Kantorovich duality is correct?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, lp-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I'm reading section *3.4 Existence of Maximisers to the Dual Problem* in [this](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Emthorpe/OTNotes) lecture notes. The proof is quite involved and requires a complicated approximation argument.

Below is my straightforward approach which is so naive that I'm not sure if it's correct. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

Let $X,Y$ be Polish spaces and $c:X \times Y \to \mathbb [0, +\infty)$. We fix Borel probability measures (b.p.m.) $\mu \in \mathcal P(X)$ and $\nu \in \mathcal P(Y)$.

- Let $\Phi_c$ be the collection of $(\varphi: X \to \mathbb R, \psi: Y \to \mathbb R) \in L_1(\mu) \times L_1(\nu)$ such that $\varphi(x)+\psi(y) \le c(x,y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.
- Let
  $$
  J (\varphi, \psi) := \int_X \varphi d \mu + \int \psi d \nu \quad \forall (\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c.
  $$
- We assume a regularity condition that there are $c_X: X \to \mathbb R$ and $c_Y: Y \to \mathbb R$ such that $c_X \in L_1(\mu), c_Y \in L_1 (\nu)$, and $c (x, y) \le c_X(x)+c_Y(y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

> Then the maximization
> $$
> \sup_{(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c} J (\varphi, \psi)
> $$
> has a solution.

---

**My attempt:** We need the following essential lemma.

> [**Lemma:**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4452748/construct-the-c-transform-overline-varphi-overline-psi-of-varphi) For each $(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c$, there is an improved pair $(\overline \varphi, \overline\psi) \in \Phi_c$ such that
>
> - $J (\varphi, \psi) = J (\overline \varphi, \overline\psi)$.
> - $\varphi (x) \le c_X (x)$ and $\psi (y) \le c_Y (y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

Let $(\varphi_n, \psi_n) \subset \Phi_c$ be a maximizing sequence. Let $(\overline \varphi_n, \overline\psi_n) \in \Phi_c$ be the improved pair of $(\varphi_n, \psi_n)$ as in the *Lemma*, i.e.,

- $J (\varphi_n, \psi_n) = J (\overline \varphi_n, \overline\psi_n)$.
- $\overline \varphi_n (x) \le c_X (x)$ and $\overline \psi_n (y) \le c_Y (y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

Let
$$
\varphi := \limsup_n \overline\varphi_n \quad \text{and} \quad \psi := \limsup_n \overline \psi.
$$

Then $\varphi$ is $\mu$-measurable and $\psi$ is $\nu$-measurable. For every $n \in \mathbb N$, we have

- $\overline \varphi_n (x) \le \varphi (x) \le c_X (x)$ for all $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$.
- $\overline \psi (y) \le \psi (y) \le c_Y (y)$ for all $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$.

This means $\varphi, \psi$ are bounded by $\mu$-integrable and $\nu$-integrable functions respectively, so $\varphi \in L_1(\mu)$ and $\psi \in L_1 (\nu)$. Clearly,
$$
J(\varphi_n, \psi_n) \le J(\varphi, \psi) \quad \forall n\in \mathbb N.
$$

Hence
$$
\sup_{(\varphi, \psi) \in \Phi_c} J (\varphi, \psi) \le J(\varphi, \psi).
$$

It remains to show that $\varphi (x)+ \psi(y) \le c(x,y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$. For each $n \in \mathbb N$,
$$
\overline \varphi_n (x)+ \overline\psi_n(y) \le c(x,y)
$$
for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$. Notice that the countable union of null sets is again a null set. Then
$$
\limsup_n \overline \varphi_n (x)+ \limsup_n \overline\psi_n(y) \le c(x,y)
$$
for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$.  This completes the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that I made a stupid mistake in claiming

> $$\limsup_n \overline \varphi_n (x)+ \limsup_n \overline\psi_n(y) \le \limsup_n [\overline \varphi_n (x)+ \overline\psi_n(y)].$$

The correct proof by the author is as follows.

---

Let $(\varphi_n, \psi_n) \subset \Phi_c$ be a maximizing sequence. WLOG, we assume
$$
J (\varphi_n, \psi_n)  \ge 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Let $(\overline \varphi_n, \overline\psi_n) \in \Phi_c$ be the improved pair of $(\varphi_n, \psi_n)$ as in the *Lemma*, i.e.,

- $J (\varphi_n, \psi_n) = J (\overline \varphi_n, \overline\psi_n)$.
- $\overline \varphi_n (x) \le c_X (x)$ and $\overline \psi_n (y) \le c_Y (y)$ for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

For $(m, n)\in \mathbb N^2$, let
$$
\alpha_{m,n} : =\min \{c_X-\overline \varphi_n, m\} \quad \text{and} \quad \beta_{m,n} : =\min \{c_Y-\overline \psi_n, m\} .
$$

- Then $0 \le \alpha_{m,n} \le m$ and $0 \le \beta_{m,n} \le m$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
- This implies the sequences $(\alpha_{m,n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $(\beta_{m,n})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are bounded in $L_2(\mu)$  and $L_2(\nu)$ respectively.
- Notice that $L_2(\mu)$  and $L_2(\nu)$  are reflexive. Hence $\overline{(\alpha_{m,n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}^{L_2(\mu)}$ and $\overline{(\beta_{m,n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}^{L_2(\nu)}$ are weakly compact. By Tychonoff theorem,
  $$
  \Pi_{m \in \mathbb N} \overline{(\alpha_{m,n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}^{L_2(\mu)} \times \Pi_{m \in \mathbb N} \overline{(\beta_{m,n})_{n \in \mathbb N}}^{L_2(\nu)}
  $$
  is compact in the product of weak topologies.
- Hence there are $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots \in L_2(\mu)$ and $\beta_1, \beta_2, \ldots \in L_2(\nu)$ and a subsequence $\lambda \in \mathbb N^\mathbb N$ such that for all $m$, we have $\alpha_{m,\lambda(n)} \rightharpoonup \alpha_m$ and $\beta_{m,\lambda(n)} \rightharpoonup \beta_m$ weakly as $n \to \infty$.
- WLOG, we assume $\lambda$ is the identity map, i.e., $\lambda(n)=n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
- Also, $0 \le \alpha_{m,n} \le \alpha_{m+1,n}$ and $0 \le \beta_{m,n} \le \beta_{m+1,n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Weak convergence preserves pointwise inequalities, so
  $$
  0 \le \alpha_m \le \alpha_{m+1} \le m+1
  \quad \text{and} \quad
  0 \le \beta_m \le \beta_{m+1} \le m+1 \quad \forall m \in \mathbb N.
  $$

Let
$$
\alpha := \lim_m \alpha_m \quad \text{and} \quad \beta := \lim_m \beta_m.
$$

Above limits are well-defined by the monotonicity of $(\alpha_m)$ and $(\beta_m)$. Clearly, $\alpha$ is $\mu$-measurable and $\beta$ is $\nu$-measurable. Also, $0 \le \alpha$ and $0 \le \beta$. Let's prove that $\alpha \in L_1(\mu)$ and $\beta \in L_1 (\nu)$. Clearly,
$$
0 \le \int \alpha d \mu \le +\infty \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \le \int \beta d \nu \le +\infty.
$$

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
& \int \alpha d \mu + \int \beta d \nu \\
=&\lim_m \int \alpha_m d \mu + \lim_m \int \beta_m d \nu \quad \text{by monotone convergence} \\
=&\lim_m  \left (\int \alpha_m d \mu +  \int \beta_m d \nu \right )
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that $\alpha_{m,n} \rightharpoonup \alpha_m$ in the weak topology of $L_2(\mu)$ and that the map
$$
L_2(\mu) \to \mathbb R, f \mapsto \int f d \mu
$$
is linear continuous in the norm topology $\| \cdot \|_{L_2(\mu)}$. So
$$
\int \alpha_m d\mu = \lim_n \int \alpha_{m,n} d\mu.
$$

Similarly,
$$
\int \beta_m d\nu = \lim_n \int \beta_{m,n} d\nu.
$$

Hence
$$
\begin{align*}
& \int \alpha d \mu + \int \beta d \nu \\
=& \lim_m  \left ( \lim_n \int \alpha_{m, n} d \mu + \lim_n  \int \beta_{m, n} d \nu \right ) \\
=& \lim_m \lim_n  \left (  \int \alpha_{m, n} d \mu + \int \beta_{m, n} d \nu \right ) \\
\le& \lim_m \lim_n  \left (  \int (c_X-\overline \varphi_n) d \mu + \int (c_Y-\overline \psi_n) d \nu \right ) \\
=& \lim_n  \left (  \int (c_X-\overline \varphi_n) d \mu + \int (c_Y-\overline \psi_n) d \nu \right )
\end{align*}
$$

Notice that the integrals $\int c_X d \mu, \int \overline \varphi_n d \mu, \int c_Y d \nu, \int \overline \psi_n d \nu$ are finite, so
$$
\begin{align*}
& \int \alpha d \mu + \int \beta d \nu \\
\le& \lim_n  \left (  \int c_X d \mu - \int \overline \varphi_n d \mu + \int c_Y d \nu - \int \overline \psi_n d \nu \right ) \\
=& \lim_n (J(c_X, c_Y)- J(\overline \varphi_n, \overline \psi_n)) \\
=& J(c_X, c_Y) - \lim_n J(\overline \varphi_n, \overline \psi_n) \\
\le& J(c_X, c_Y) < +\infty.
\end{align*}
$$

It follows that
$$
\int \alpha d \mu < +\infty,
\quad
\int \beta d \nu < +\infty,
\quad
\lim_n J(\overline \varphi_n, \overline \psi_n) < +\infty.
$$

So $\alpha \in L_1 (\mu)$ and $\beta \in L_1 (\nu)$. Let
$$
\varphi := c_X - \alpha \quad \text{and} \quad \psi := c_Y-\beta.
$$

Clearly, $\varphi \in L_1 (\mu)$ and $\psi \in L_1 (\nu)$. It follows from above inequality that
$$
J(\varphi, \psi) = J(c_X, c_Y) - J(\alpha, \beta) \ge \lim_n J(\overline \varphi_n, \overline \psi_n).
$$

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
& \varphi (x)+ \psi(y) \\
=& c_X(x)-\alpha(x) +c_Y(y)-\beta(y) \\
=& c_X(x) - \lim_m \alpha_m (x) + c_Y(y) - \lim_m \beta_m (y) \\
=& c_X(x) - \lim_m \lim_n \alpha_{m, n} (x) + c_Y(y) - \lim_m \lim_n \beta_{m,n}(y) \\
=& \lim_m \lim_n (c_{X} (x)-\alpha_{m, n} (x)) +  \lim_m \lim_n (c_Y(y) - \beta_{m,n}(y)) \\
=& \lim_m \lim_n \left [ \max \{ \overline\varphi_n(x), c_X(x)-m\} + \max \{ \overline\psi_n(y), c_Y(y)-m\}  \right ].
\end{align*}
$$

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
& \max \{ \overline\varphi_n(x), c_X(x)-m\} + \max \{ \overline\psi_n(y), c_Y (y)-m\} \\
=& c_X(x) + c_Y(y)+\max \{ \overline\varphi_n(x) -c_X(x), -m\} + \max \{ \overline\psi_n(y) - c_Y (y), -m\}  \\
\le & c_X(x) + c_Y(y)+\max \{ \overline\varphi_n(x) -c_X(x)+\overline\psi_n(y) - c_Y (y), -m\} \quad (\star)\\
\le & c_X(x) + c_Y(y)+\max \{ c(x,y)-c_X(x) - c_Y (y), -m\} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Here $(\star)$ follows from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454218/let-a-b-c-le-0-then-maxa-c-maxb-c-le-maxab-c) result. It follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
& \varphi (x)+ \psi(y) \\
\le & \lim_m \left [c_X(x) + c_Y(y)+\max \{ c(x,y) -c_X(x)- c_Y (y), -m\} \right ] \\
= & c_X(x) + c_Y(y) + [c(x,y)-c_X(x) - c_Y (y)] \\
= & c(x,y).
\end{align*}
$$